# How to make keyboard shortcut for wine application?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I know that launchers can be made, but is the same true for keyboard shortcuts? I've tried myself, with just a copy and paste of the directory to no avail. I apologize, but I'm new to linux, can someone please chime in here?

Edit:
Not duplicate because xbindkeys does not work on my PC. Had to use both/the stock keyboard shortcuts setup.

Comment: I understand that the `xbindkeys` methods doesn't apply to your case. Did you try any of the other mentioned methods, in particular [Luis' answer](/a/304834/175814)? The linked question features all relevant ways to create custom keyboard shortcuts under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this wont benefit long-time Linux users, but for new Linux users like me, coming from Windows, I would appreciate if such a guide was created. so here it is :))

OK, I've found the solution!

Xbindkeys is a nice program, given that you can try your newly made shortcut and it'll give you a reply from the terminal, but in my case it would not work any time but when I would push the *run command* button. I've heard its because `gnome-shortcuts` has higher priority.

This may be because my particular type of Ubuntu is Zorin.

But, regardless, after you have tried you shortcut and are ready to use it, open system setting, keyboard, shortcuts, new shortcut and just paste the path into the *command* box, setup button configuration, done!

and remember, any spaces in your path name must be preceded by a `\`. So
since you are using wine to run the program, put `wine` before everything, like this;

```
wine /home/yourrealusername/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS2/Photoshop.exe
```

I have it set so this will open when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, and you must logout and login after doing this (or reset any way doesn't matter). Then it should be smooth sailing!

Comment: Don't forget to set the `WINEPREFIX` variable to the path of the appropriate Wine runtime environment: `env WINEPREFIX=/home/yourrealusername/.wine wine <EXE_PATH>`! This may not be relevant for the default environment, but for others, which you should use for every individual application anyway.

Comment: On another note, this is the same as [Luis' answer](/a/304834/175814) from the [linked question](/q/254424).

Comment: simply putting the wine command didn't work for me. Finally got it with `sh -c "env WINEPREFIX=/home/<username>/.wine wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/1Password.exe"`. Swap in your <username> accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Open settings then go to keyboard then select the shortcuts tab then the plus sign to create a new shortcut.

You can also use the xbindkeys program

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
```

Launch them both and use the xbindkeys-config to set up the shortcuts

Comment: From what I understand, `xbindkeys` cannot be used to run custom, arbitrary shell commands upon pressing a key combination.